# iTunes Beta testing and Distribution profile

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ad-hoc-distribution, beta-testing

I have a small question about `iTunes` connect `beta testing`.

So for this we have to upload a build to the app store and then enable internal tester. As `Xcode` does not allow us to sign an app with `Ad Hoc` provisioning profile to upload it to app store and it has to be the distribution profile to upload it to app store.

So my question is that when i sign it with distribution profile the `push notification` use the production server, and may be my production server is not ready at that time so how should we can get around this issue.

So there are two thing one the production server for the `push notification` and other is the production server for API calls. I can always use development server URLs but when i sign with `distribution` profile. I Think it will automatically use the production server for the `Push notifications`

Answer (score 0):

Use the distribution certificate, and in your development server use the same distribution push certificate .PEM (you can re-use this .pem later on your distribution server).

Comment: But the issue is that i already have the production server setup and i can't touch the production server because i already have my earlier version of the app using that. So with the solution that you are telling me i will be having same certificate on my both development and production server and if i use the development server URLs then from which server i will be getting the push messages from development or production?

Comment: If you have the same push cert in development and production server, but not the same devices or accounts where you want to send the push notifications, you should have no problem on sending push notifications from your development server to your "development or testing" accounts (stored in development) and you do not need to change your production server.